# Неправильно записывается JSON в файл

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

Код:

```py
import json 

def test(key, val):

    xs = open('test.json', 'r+')
    x = xs.read()
    y = {key:val} 
    z = json.loads(x) 
    z.update(y) 
    xs.seek(0)
    xs.truncate(0)
    json.dump(json.dumps(z, indent=4), xs)

test('testing', 'testers')
```

До выполнения кода test.json выглядит вот так:

```
{
    "one": "two"
}
```

После выполнения кода уже вот так:

```
"{\n    \"one\": \"two\",\n    \"testing\": \"testers\"\n}"
```

Как я могу нормально записать json данные без \n и прочего лишнего?

Comment: json.dump(z, xs, indent=4)  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот здесь вы сначала словарь превращаете в json-строку (метод `dumps`), потом эту строку еще раз преобразовываете в json (метод `dump`):

```
json.dump(json.dumps(z, indent=4), xs)
```

Нужно использовать один из этих методов, но не оба одновременно.

Для записи объекта в файл в виде json используйте метод `dump`:

```
json.dump(z, xs, indent=4)
```

Тот же самый результат можно получить преобразовав словарь в json-строку, потом записав эту строку в файл с помощью `write`:

```
xs.write(json.dumps(z, indent=4))
```